# Admin cannot add page, article, product

Tags: wordpress, admin, rights

I currently run a WordPress website which recently started to bug me. I am the only admin on the page and I suddenly cannot add a product, page or anything for that matter. Instead of the publish button there is a "send for review" or something button. Even if I hit that button it says I do not have the rights to do it.

I have tried:
- adding a new administrator but it has the same effect
- disabled ALL plugins and tried again = nothing
- changed privileges in the database (table wp_usermeta)

Help would be extremely welcomed!

Comment: Seems like you have your database damaged

Answer (score 1):

One very possible cause: You [ran out of space](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/no-publish-but-submit-for-review-button-displayed-to-site-admin#post-1641510) to append to your database, with your provider.

Hence no saving, your provider does not allow any new posts to be published due to not enough space, so the **Publish** button is invisible, and instead you have **Send for review**

Comment: I have contacted my hosting admin and he guaranteed me I have a lot of free space... :/

Comment: Did you try a fresh install of wp?